# Dynamically Parsing a worksheet in Pandas using Python 3

Tags: python, pandas

My question is regarding parsing worksheets in Panda (Python 3).

Right now my code looks like this:

```
var = input("Enter the path for the Excel file you want to use: ")
import pandas as pd
xl = pd.ExcelFile(var)
df = xl.parse("HelloWorld")
df.head()
```

with my code parsing the worksheet "HelloWorld" within an excel file the user inputs.  However, sometimes the worksheet within the file will not be called "HelloWorld" in which case the parsing code will fail.

Does anyone know how to set the variable "df" to dynamically read the name of the worksheet within the excel file.  There will always be only ONE worksheet in these excel files so whatever worksheet is in the file, I want my code to read.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.excel.ExcelFile.parse.html

You can pass in the sheet number instead of the name.

```
var = input("Enter the path for the Excel file you want to use: ")
import pandas as pd
xl = pd.ExcelFile(var)
df = xl.parse(sheetname=0)
df.head()
```

Comment: the sheetname defaults to zero, so if you just leave it out, it should do what you want

Comment: Good point, I was trying to be explicit in my answer.  Do you think I should edit the sheetname parameter out?

Comment: Answer's good as it is, it's just worth pointing out that it's more explicit than necessary :)